# How to count specific products?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `product` and its columns are `maker`, `type` and `model`. I want to get the makers who produce 6 product types and more than one model. Here is something I am trying:

```
select maker, type 
from product 
group by maker
having count(distinct type) = 6 
   and count(distinct model) > 1 ;
```

It gives error.

If I say I need 1 type and query is:

```
select maker, min(type) 
from product 
group by maker
having count(distinct type) = 1 
   and count(distinct model) > 1 ;
```

then it works. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first query the error is produced by the attribute `type`, which is in the select clause, but not in the group by clause. This is due to the fact that there are different values of `type` for each group. So, instead of writing:

```
select maker, type from product group by maker
having count(distinct type) = 6 and count(distinct model) > 1
```

you should either remove `type`:

```
select maker from product group by maker
having count(distinct type) = 6 and count(distinct model) > 1
```

or use an aggregation function for it, like in the second query:

```
select maker, min(type) from product group by maker
having count(distinct type) = 6 and count(distinct model) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is for databases with analytic function support:

```
select
  maker,
  type
from
(
  select
    maker,
    type,
    count(distinct type) over (partition by maker) as types,
    count(distinct model) over (partition by maker) as models
  from
    product
)
where
  types = 6
  and models > 1
;
```

And this is for databases without analytic functions:

```
select
  maker,
  type
from
  product
where
  maker in 
  (
    select
      maker
    from
      product
    group by
      maker
    having
      count(distinct type) = 6
      and count(distinct model) > 1
  )
;
```